# run javascript on div click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wonder if someone can help, basically i have this javascript which fades in a div when the user scrolls down a page, however, i want to put a condition on the javascript to say only fade after the user has clicked another div element.

for instance i need the user to read a piece of text before they scroll down the page and this div fades in, on this piece of text is a div called

so once the user has read the text they will click 'exit_profile_intro4' which will close the text box,
only then do i want the javascript for the scroll and fade in div to work. can someone please show me how i can do this: i've tried

```
<script>
$('div.exit_intro4').click(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
       var leftToBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
       var distanceFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       if( distanceFromTop > 300 && !$("profile_intro_case5").is(":visible") 
          && leftToBottom > 1000 && !$(".profile_intro_case5").is(":animated")) {
                $(".profile_intro_case5").fadeIn(1000);
       }else if($(".profile_intro_case5").is(":visible") && (distanceFromTop < 300 || leftToBottom < 1000) && !$(".profile_intro_case5").is(":animated")){
                $(".profile_intro_case5").fadeOut();
      }
   });
});
   </script>
```

original:

```
<script>
 $(window).scroll(function(){
       var leftToBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
       var distanceFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       if( distanceFromTop > 300 && !$("profile_intro_case5").is(":visible") 
          && leftToBottom > 1000 && !$(".profile_intro_case5").is(":animated")) {
                $(".profile_intro_case5").fadeIn(1000);
       }else if($(".profile_intro_case5").is(":visible") && (distanceFromTop < 300 || leftToBottom < 1000) && !$(".profile_intro_case5").is(":animated")){
                $(".profile_intro_case5").fadeOut();
      }
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: The only issue I see with what you have is that multiple clicks will add multiple handlers.  What is the issue you are having?

Comment: any error codes from the console?

Comment: Please don't add events inside a click event. That's just asking for trouble. Use conditional state instead (see below).

Comment: Note that depending on a click handler on a div is an accessibility fail because it makes your page unusable for people who choose not to or are physically unable to use a mouse or other pointing device. In general it is better to use an anchor element because it is accessible via the keyboard...

Answer (score 3):

Add a state to the scroll event.

```
(function() {
  var user_can_scroll = false;
  $("div.exit_intro4").click(function(e) {
    /* do your thing */
    user_can_scroll = true;
  });

  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if (user_can_scroll) {
      /* do your scroll thing */
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why your code would be incorrect (without actually running it), however you assign a click like this

```
$('div.exit_intro4').click( // Function
```

Yet, you say you want to trigger it when "exit_profile_intro4" is clicked. Perhaps it should be this.

```
$('div.exit_profile_intro4').click( // Function
```